# One-Many List box on a View and pull description from third entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My background is in C#.Net Win Forms, I am currently learning to build web applications using EF 6.1 and MVC 5. I have watched several videos on a training website about MVC, html, jquery and google is my friend, typically. However, I have searched and searched for this answer but have not found exactly what I need.

I am using Database First approach form EF and for this problem I have three Tables.

```
Event {int Id, datetime CreatedDate, varchar(50) Description}
EventType {int EventId, int TypeEventId}
TypeEvent {int Id, varchar(50) Description}
```

I have a 1-Many Relationship on Event and EventType and another on TypeEvent to EventType.

I am wanting to create a view that will allow me to create an Event on a single page. Since an Event can have multiple Types, I would like those in a multi-select box. I have used the

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.EventType ...)
```

But I can not get the description to work properly. Currently I am using all the default controllers that the scaffolding would create from the EF. I think I might need to make my own controller or create a partial view for the dropdown box.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

**Edit**

I have been able to get my 1-Many ListBox up and working with Multiselect. However, I am running into a slight problem with passing model data, to my post action.

**Model**

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    //This is my primary Entity
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    //Properties for ListBox
    public IEnumerable<int> selectedTypeEventId;
    public IEnumerable<TypeEvent> TypeEvent { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        EventViewModel m = new EventViewModel();
        List<TypeEvent> listTypeEvent = db.TypeEvents.ToList();
        m.TypeEvent = listTypeEvent;

        return View(m);
    }

    // POST: Event/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel m, IEnumerable<int> selectedTypeEventId)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<EventType> listEventType = new List<EventType>();
            db.Events.Add(m.Event);
            db.SaveChanges();
            foreach (int i in selectedTypeEventId)
            {
                EventType et = new EventType();
                et.EventId = m.Event.Id;
                et.TypeEventId = i;
                db.EventTypes.Add(et);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

**View**

```
@model TMS.Models.EventViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Event</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Event.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Event Types", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.selectedTypeEventId, new SelectList(Model.TypeEvent, "Id", "Description"), new { @id = "TypeEvent", @multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control", @name = "TypeList" })
            </div>
        </div>
}

//This turns ListBox into DropDownCheckBoxList
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#TypeEvent').multiselect();
        });
    </script>
}
```

When I post this form I have to added an IEnumerable to my controller to pick up the data from the list box. All of the other Data is automatically fed into the Model through the

```
@Html.EditFor
```

How can I add the listbox selected data to the Model Info and not have to pass in an extra parameter on my Post Action?

**Edit**
I'll just say its been a long day new years and I'm just overlooking code. In my model I changed

```
public IEnumerable<int> selectedTypeEventId;
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<int> selectedTypeEventId { get; set; }
```

helps to have the get/set properties....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following viewmodel and fill the TypeEvents from your controller

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int TypeEventId    
    public IEnumerable<TypeEvent> TypeEvents {get;set;}

}


public class YourController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateEvent()
    {
        var viewModel = new EventViewModel();

        viewModel.TypeEvents = ... // fill Data for DropDownList here

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEvent(EventViewModel viewModel)
    {
         // You should have all the data you need in the viewModel
    }
}
```

then in the view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeEventId, new SelectList(Model.TypeEvents,"Id","Description") )
```

the post action of your controller should do the database / businesslogic calls

If you want to be able to add multiple TypeEvents at once you have to do this differently... Make a Repository with for example a Dictionary with a GUID as Key and add this Guid to the viewModel. Make 2 more Controller Post Actions, one to add a new EventType and one to remove it. The part where you show what EventTypes are attached should go in a partial view, which is filled with the 2 actions and resent to the client. I had to do this recently and it looked like this:

```
@model Apps4KidsWeb.Models.AddAppViewModel

@using Apps4KidsWeb.Domain

<table>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in Model.OperatingSystems)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@operatingSystems[item.Value]</td>
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(
                                        "Remove",
                                        "RemoveOperatingSystem",
                                        "Admin",
                                        new { guid = Model.Guid, id = item.Key },
                                        new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                            UpdateTargetId = "operatingSystems"
                                        })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and the containing view:

```
@model Apps4KidsWeb.Models.AddAppViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add App";
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = "Add App";
}
<div class="float">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <div id="categories">
        @Html.Partial("_Categories", Model)
    </div>



    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCategory", "Admin",
    new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "categories", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Guid)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category)
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />    
    }
</div>
<div class="float">
    <h3>Operating Systems</h3>
    <div id="operatingSystems">
        @Html.Partial("_OperatingSystems", Model)
    </div>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOperatingSystem", "Admin",
    new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "operatingSystems", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Guid)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OS)
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />  
    }
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddApp", "Admin"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Guid)

    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Weiter" />
    </p>

}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The controller:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an operating system to the AddAppViewModel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Guid">The Guid of the item</param>
    /// <param name="OS">The id of the operating system</param>
    /// <returns>PartialView _OperatingSystems</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOperatingSystem(string Guid, int OS)
    {
        var viewmodel = EditedAppRepository.GetInstance().GetApp(Guid);
        viewmodel.AddOperatingSystem(OS);
        return PartialView("_OperatingSystems", viewmodel);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes an operating sytem from the AddAppViewModel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Guid">The Guid of the item</param>
    /// <param name="id">The id of the operating system</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveOperatingSystem(string Guid, int id)
    {
        var viewmodel = EditedAppRepository.GetInstance().GetApp(Guid);
        viewmodel.RemoveOperatingSystem(id);
        return PartialView("_OperatingSystems", viewmodel);
    }
```

and the Repository:

```
using Apps4KidsWeb.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Apps4KidsWeb.Models
{
    public class EditedAppRepository
    {
        #region singleton

        private static EditedAppRepository singleton;

        public static EditedAppRepository GetInstance()
        {
            if (singleton == null)
            {
                singleton = new EditedAppRepository();                
            }
            return singleton;
        }

        private EditedAppRepository()
        {
            this.repository = new Dictionary<string, AddAppViewModel>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region fields

        private Dictionary<string, AddAppViewModel> repository;

        #endregion

        #region methods

        public AddAppViewModel CreateNewApp(IApp app)
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            AddAppViewModel result = new AddAppViewModel(app) { Guid = guid };
            repository.Add(guid, result);
            result.Saved += OnAppSaved;
            return result;
        }

        public AddAppViewModel CreateNewApp(IRecommendationEx recommendation) 
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            AddAppViewModel result = new AddAppViewModel(recommendation) { Guid = guid };
            repository.Add(guid, result);
            result.Saved += OnAppSaved;
            return result;
        }

        public AddAppViewModel CreateNewApp()
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            AddAppViewModel result = new AddAppViewModel() { Guid=guid  };
            repository.Add(guid, result);
            result.Saved += OnAppSaved;
            return result;
        }

        public AddAppViewModel GetApp(string guid)
        {
            if (guid != null && repository.ContainsKey(guid))
            {
                return repository[guid];
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void OnAppSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddAppViewModel model = (AddAppViewModel)sender;
            repository.Remove(model.Guid);
        }

        public byte[] GetAppPicture(string guid, int id)
        {
            return repository[guid].Images[id];
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll start putting this into my project and see where it leads. It seems like a lot of work when using frameworks that are suppose to do a lot automatically apparently  MVC scaffolding and EF are only good if you are using one table at a time.

Comment: Pretty sure there are simpler solutions however you would have to use javascript to code your multiselectlist...